# Linux is not allowing me to access a fixed region of memory

Tags: c, linux, memory-management

I have some data stored in a FLASH memory that I need to access with C pointers to be able to make a non-Linux graphics driver work (I think this requirement is DMA related, not sure). Calling read works, but I don't want to have intermediate RAM buffers between the FLASH and the non-Linux driver.

However, just creating a pointer and storing the address that I want on it is making Linux emit an exception about invalid access on me.

```
void *ptr = 0xdeadbeef;
int a = *ptr; // invalid access!
```

What am I missing here? And could someone point me to a material to make this concepts clear for me?

I'm reading about [mmap](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mmap.2.html) but I'm not sure that this is what I need.

Comment: Maybe I am just not understanding the context, but to me the question doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

Comment: I think when your virtual address is being generated for your program,the address `0Xdeadbeef` must be lying out of that Virtual address space for this program.

Comment: If your Linux uses virtual to physical address translation, then, in order to access the device's memory, you have to create a virtual to physical memory mapping with read/write permission. Dereferencing a pointer to a location not mapped to physical/device memory is going to cause a page fault/exception/signal/etc and crash your system or program.

Comment: You've answered your question yourself - mmap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you have is that linux runs your program in a [virtual address space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space). So every address you use directly in the code (like 0xdeadbeef) is a virtual address that gets translated by the [memory management unit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) into a physical address which is not necessarily the same as your virtual address. This allows easy separation of multiple independent processes and other stuff like paging, etc.

The problem is now, that in your case no physical address is mapped to the virtual address 0xdeadbeef causing the kernel to abort execution.

The call mmap you already found asks the kernel to assign a specific file (from a specific offset) to a virtual address of your process. Note that the returning address of mmap could be a completely different address. So don't make any assumptions about the virtual address you get.

Therefore there are examples with mmap and /dev/mem out there where the offset for the memory device is the physical address. After the kernel was able to assign the file from the offset you gave to a virtual address of your process you can access the memory area asif it were a direct access.

After you don't need the area anymore don't forget to munmap the area. Otherwise you'll cause something similar to a memory leak.

One problem with the /dev/mem method is that the user running the process needs access to this device. This could introduce a security issue (e.g. [Samsung recently introduced such a security hole](http://www.h-online.com/open/news/item/Samsung-promises-patch-for-critical-smartphone-vulnerability-1773557.html) in their hand held devices)

A more secure way is the way described in a article i found ([The Userspace I/O HOWTO](http://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/uio-howto.html)) as you still have control about the memory areas accessable by the user's process.

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. I'll apply this to my problem and give some feedback here.

Comment: @haole I'll be happy to get some feedback about your success. I just updated the answer a bit as I found it a bit hard to read after my quick edit an hour ago. I also removed the fact error that mmap directly maps physical addresses. As others already have pointed out this only works in conjunction with /dev/mem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the memory differently. Basically you need to open /dev/mem and use mmap(). (as you suggested). Simple example:

```
int openMem(unsigned int address, unsigned int size)
{
int             mmapFD;
int             page_size;
unsigned int    page_start_address;

/* Minimum page size for the mmapped region. */
mask = size - 1;

/* Get the page size. */
page_size = (int) sysconf(_SC_PAGE_SIZE);

/* We have to map shared memory to beginning of memory page so adjust 
 * memory address accordingly. */
page_start_address = address - (address % page_size);

/* Open the file that will be mapped. */

if((mmapFD = open("/dev/mem", (O_RDWR | O_SYNC))) == -1)
{
    printf("Opening shared memory device failed\n");
    return -1;
}

mmap_base_address = mmap(0, size, (PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE), MAP_SHARED, mmapFD, (off_t)page_start_address & ~mask);
if(mmap_base_address == MAP_FAILED)
{
    printf("Mapping memory failed\n");
    return -1;
}
return 0;
}

unsigned int *getAddress(unsigned int address)
{
unsigned int    log_address;

log_address = (int)((off_t)mmap_base_address + ((off_t)address & mask));

return (unsigned int*)log_address;
}

...

result = openMem(address, 0x10000);

if (result < 0)
    return result;

target_address =  getValue(address);

*(unsigned int*)target_address = value;
```

This would set "value" to "address".

Comment: Just a question: Won't being able to access /dev/mem by anyone introduce a security issue? I just remember having read that Samsung did something like that on one of their products introducing a huge security issue.

Comment: Could be. I usually work with embedded Linux, so this is not such an issue (in the final product there is no user access to OS).

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `ioremap` - something like:

```
void *myaddr = ioremap(0xdeadbeef, size);
```

where size is the size of your memory region. You probably want to use a page-aligned address for the first argument, e.g. `0xdeadb000` - but I expect your actual device isn't at "0xdeadbeef" anyways.

Edit: The call to ioremap must be done from a driver!